# issue in name space and use in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

UI Code in: `resources\views\DistributorRegistration.php`

```
<?php

namespace resources\views;

class DistributorRegitrationForm
{
    public function distributorRegitrationFormHtml(){
        return  '<h1>Hello</h1>';
    }
}

?>
```

In Controler Class: `app\Http\Controllers\DistributorRegistration.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use resources\views\DistributorRegistration;


class DistributorRegistration  extends Controller
{
    function VestigePOS_GRNHandler(Request $request){
    //$id = $request->input('id');
    return view(DistributorRegitrationForm::distributorRegitrationFormHtml()) ;
    }

}    
?>
```

I receive this error when I call the controller in routes:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DistributorRegitrationForm' not found

Comment: please correct 'use resources\views\DistributorRegistration;' to 'use resources\views\DistributorRegistrationForm;' and try.

Comment: yes done...but still same error is occurred

Comment: try this, I hope it will work - return view(resources\views\DistributorRegistration\DistributorRegitrationForm::distributorRegitrationFormHtml()) ; or view(\resources\views\DistributorRegistration\DistributorRegitrationForm::distributorRegitrationFormHtml()) ;

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\resources\views\DistributorRegistration\DistributorRegitrationForm' not found please suggest some needfull

Comment: please suggest something

Comment: can you paste complete error log?

Comment: FatalThrowableError in DistributorRegistration.php line 12:
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DistributorRegitrationForm' not found
in DistributorRegistration.php line 12
at DistributorRegistration->VestigePOS_GRNHandler()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(DistributorRegistration), 'VestigePOS_GRNHandler'), array()) in Controller.php line 76
at Controller->callAction('VestigePOS_GRNHandler', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(DistributorRegistration), object(Route), 'V

Comment: okay great! If you want to share your solution here, please share it.It may be helpful for anyone else.Thank!

Comment: i create a folder (UI) in App folder and move all Ui classes in it. and give namespace App\UI\DistributorRegistration..it'll be fix....

Comment: solve this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989829/throw-exception-in-laravel-5-2